# Does the integral of the vis-viva equation have any meaning?

Tags: energy-conservation, orbital-motion, integration, celestial-mechanics

If orbital speed of an elliptical orbit can be described by

$$
v(r) =\sqrt{GM\left(\frac{2}{r}-\frac{1}{a}\right)},
$$

then what would the meaning of its ($\mathrm{d}r$) integral be?

Comment: How is asking for the physical meaning of an operation *not* a conceptual question, but instead a homework question? OP doesn't anywhere state they need help with the integral...

Answer (score 2):

Given any $v(r)$, the integral over space can be transformed as follows,
$$\int v\,\mathrm{d}r=\int v\,\frac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t=\int v^2\,\mathrm{d}t.$$
Recalling that kinetic energy is $\sim mv^2$, then the right-most integral is proportional to the integral of kinetic energy over time, which yields an [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)). So the original integral is something like an action per unit mass, I suppose.
While the action is fairly common, I don't think the integral on the left-most side is a particularly common operation.

Answer (score 1):

$$\oint v_r \mathrm dr,$$
i.e. the *radial component of the velocity* integrated around a radial orbit, is a useful quantity, sometimes called the radial action. For example, it is an [adiabatic invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_invariant#Classical_mechanics_%E2%80%93_action_variables), meaning that it is preserved under (among other things) a change to the gravitational potential, as long as the change happens over many orbits. Also, it is used in the construction of [action-angle coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action-angle_coordinates).

However, I can't think of a context where it makes sense to put the total speed $v\equiv |\vec v|$ (and not just $v_r$) as the integrand. Putting the total speed in the above integral would actually just yield 0, i.e.
$$\oint |\vec v| \mathrm dr =0,$$
since the ascending and descending contributions would cancel.